# Generic function to parse numbers fails with "FromStr is not implemented"

Tags: generics, rust

I have this generic function in my Rust code:

```
fn test<T>(text: &str) -> T {
    text.parse::<T>()
}
```

The idea is that the caller would do something like

```
test::<u64>("2313");
```

But the compilation fails with this message

```
error: the trait `core::str::FromStr` is not implemented for the type `T` [E0277]
```

I just started learning Rust yesterday, so this is probably a very basic question that I've failed to find the answer to.

Comment: Have you read the [Traits chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html)? It explains the basics and should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like the error message states, `T` needs to implement `core::str::FromStr` in order to be applicable for the `parse` function. The type signature of `parse` is:

```
fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> where F: FromStr
```

Which limits the sort of `F` (or, in your case `T`) you can use to those implementing `FromStr`. Your other problem is the type returned by `test`; it should be the same as the one of `parse` - a `Result`.

When you fix those issues, your function will work:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn test<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> Result<T, T::Err> {
    text.parse::<T>()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", test::<u64>("2313"));
}
```

> Ok(2313)

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a generic type parameter `T`, you don't know anything about that type. It could be `i32`, `String`, `()` or `PinkElephant`; only two of those can be parsed from a string.

The way to restrict types in Rust is by *trait bounds*: we explicitly request a specific behavior from the type. Like "this type can be any type but I at least want the possibility to clone one instance of this type" (this would be the `Clone` trait). You can (and should!) read more about the topic of traits [in the dedicated chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html).

So what feature do you expect from your type `T`? You want to create an instance of `T` from a string by using [`str::parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse). The function signature of `parse()` is:

```
fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> 
    where F: FromStr
```

It also takes this generic parameter `F` and bounds it with the trait `FromStr`. Thus, in order to use `parse()`, *your* type parameter `T` also needs to implement `FromStr`. Your function could look like this:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn test<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> T {
    text.parse::<T>().expect("string was invalid!")
}
```

What is this `expect()` you ask? Well... we are touching another topic here: error handling. There is also a [chapter on that topic in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html), which you should read. In short: you need to somehow handle the case that the string was invalid (like `"peter"` when you were trying to parse an integer). `expect()` is probably the wrong way here: it just panics (aborts the thread) when the parsing did not succeed.

Also remember that there is a compiler error index, in which you can read more about a specific error. [Here is the entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0277) for your error E0277.